# Rails 4: Has_one polymorphic association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models `Purchase` and `Address`. I'm trying to make `Address` polymorphic so I can reuse it in my `Purchase` model for `has_one :billing_address` and `has_one :shipping_address`. Here's my schema:

```
create_table "addresses", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "street_address"
  t.string   "street_address2"
  t.string   "zip_code"
  t.string   "phone_number"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "state_id"
  t.string   "city"
  t.string   "addressable_type" #<-- 
  t.integer  "addressable_id"   #<--
end
```

address model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end
```

purchase model:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shipping_address, as: :addressable
  has_one :billing_address, as: :addressable
  ...
end
```

Everything looks fine to me, but my Rspec tests fail:

```
    Failures:

      1) Purchase should have one shipping_address
         Failure/Error: it { should have_one(:shipping_address) }
           Expected Purchase to have a has_one association called shipping_address (ShippingAddress does not exist)
         # ./spec/models/purchase_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      2) Purchase should have one billing_address
         Failure/Error: it { should have_one(:billing_address) }
           Expected Purchase to have a has_one association called billing_address (BillingAddress does not exist)
         # ./spec/models/purchase_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It doesn't seem to be detecting that the association is polymorphic. Even in my console:

```
    irb(main):001:0> p = Purchase.new
    => #<Purchase id: nil, user_id: nil, order_date: nil, total_cents: 0, total_currency: "USD", shipping_cents: 0, shipping_currency: "USD", tax_cents: 0, tax_currency: "USD", subtotal_cents: 0, subtotal_currency: "USD", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, status: nil>
    irb(main):002:0> p.shipping_address
    => nil
    irb(main):003:0> p.build_shipping_address
    NameError: uninitialized constant Purchase::ShippingAddress
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Have you tried to use `t.references :addressable, polymorphic: true`?

Comment: @zishe Is that different from writing the addressable_type and addressable_id column names out by hand?

Comment: I don't know. You can try and we will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the `:class_name` option for the `has_one` association, as the class name can't be inferred from the association name i.e., `:shipping_address` and `:billing_address` in your case doesn't give an idea that they refer to class `Address`.

Update the `Purchase` model as below:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shipping_address, class_name: "Address", as: :addressable
  has_one :billing_address, class_name: "Address", as: :addressable
  ## ...
end
```

Comment: So obvious, didn't noticed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misunderstood what polymorphic associations are for.  They allow it to belong to more than one model,  Address here is always going to belong to Purchase.

What you've done allows an Address to belong to say, Basket or Purchase.  The addressable_type is always going to be Purchase.  It won't be ShippingAddress or BillingAddress which I think you think it will be.

`p.build_shipping_address` doesn't work because there isn't a shipping address model.

Add `class_name: 'Address'` and it will let you do it.  However it still won't work the way you expect.

I think what you actually want is single table inheritance.  Just having a type column on address

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shipping_address
  has_one :billing_address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase
  ...
end

class ShippingAddress < Address
end

class BillingAddress < Address
end
```

This should be fine because shipping and billing address will have the same data, if you've got lots of columns that are only in one or the other it's not the way to go.

Another implementation would be to have shipping_address_id and billing_address_id on the Purchase model.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shipping_address, class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :billing_address, class_name: 'Address'
end
```

The `belongs_to :shipping_address` will tell rails to look for shipping_address_id with the class name telling it to look in the addresses table.

Comment: Great point, I decided to go with single table inheritance instead of polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat of a convention to name the polymorphic relation something that ends in "able". This makes sense if it conveys some sort of action. For example and image is "viewable", an account is "payable", etc. However, sometimes it is hard to come up with a term that ends in "able" and when forced to find such a term, it can even cause a bit of confusion.

Polymorphic associations often show ownership. For this case in particular, I would would define the Address model as follows:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address_owner, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end
```

Using `:address_owner` for the relation name should help clear up any confusion as it makes it clear that an address belongs to something or someone. It could belong to a user, a person, a customer, an order, or a business, etc.

I would argue against single table inheritance as shipping and billing addresses are still at the end of the day, just addresses, i.e, there is no morphing going on. In contrast, a person, an order, or a business are cleary very different in nature and therefore make a good case for polymorphism.

In the case of an order, we still want the columns `address_owner_type` and `address_owner_id` to reflect that an order belongs to a customer. So the question remains: How do we show that an order has a billing address and a shipping address?

The solution that I would go with is to add foreign keys to the orders table for the shipping address and billing address. The Order class would look something like the following:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many    :addresses, :as => :address_owner
  belongs_to  :shipping_address, :class_name => 'Address'
  belongs_to  :billing_address, :class_name => 'Address'
  ...
end
```

Note: I am using Order for the class name in favor of Purchase, as an order reflects both the business and customer sides of a transaction, whereas, a purchase is something that a customer does.

If you want, you can then define the opposite end of the relation for Address:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address_owner, :polymorphic => true
  has_one :shipping_address, :class_name => 'Order', :foreign_key => 'shipping_address_id'
  has_one :billing_address, :class_name => 'Order', :foreign_key => 'billing_address_id'
  ...
end
```

The one other bit of code to clear up yet, is how to set the shipping and billing addresses? For this, I would override the respective setters on the Order model. The Order model would then look like the following:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many    :addresses, :as => :address_owner
  belongs_to  :shipping_address, :class_name => 'Address'
  belongs_to  :billing_address, :class_name => 'Address'
  ...

  def shipping_address=(shipping_address)
    if self.shipping_address
      self.shipping_address.update_attributes(shipping_address)
    else
      new_address = Address.create(shipping_address.merge(:address_owner => self))
      self.shipping_address_id = new_address.id  # Note of Caution: Replacing this line with "self.shipping_address = new_address" would re-trigger this setter with the newly created Address, which is something we definitely don't want to do
    end
  end

  def billing_address=(billing_address)
    if self.billing_address
      self.billing_address.update_attributes(billing_address)
    else
      new_address = Address.create(billing_address.merge(:address_owner => self))
      self.billing_address_id = new_address.id
    end
  end
end
```

This solution solves the problem by defining two relations for an address. The `has_one` and `belongs_to` relation allows us to track shipping and billing addresses, whereas the `polymorphic` relation shows that the shipping and billing addresses belong to an order. This solution gives us the best of both worlds.